# tensorflow learn - initialize variables

Tags: tensorflow, skflow

I have a problem with getting started with “tensforflow learn”  (previously called skflow).

My problem ?

I am not able to run even the simplest example of a DNN

The  example below throws an error

```
**RuntimeError: Init operations did not make model ready.  Init op: 
init,  init fn: None, error: Variables not initialized: global_step, 
linear/_weight..*
```

and in jupyter notebook the kernel abruptly ends ?

Am I missing anything or is it a bug ?

```
from tensorflow.contrib import learn
from sklearn import datasets, metrics, cross_validation
iris = datasets.load_iris()
classifier = learn.DNNClassifier(hidden_units=[10,20,10],n_classes = 3)
classifier.fit(iris.data, iris.target, steps=200, batch_size=32)
```

P.S : I have tf version 9

```
import tensorflow as tf 
tf.__version__
```

P.S: 
Could please someone with enough reputation create a tag **tensorflow-learn**
I find it unfortunate that Google has renamed skflow to tensorflow learn. there is a risk of confusion with the [tflearn](http://tflearn.org/) library (Unless of course this is intended.)

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

after restarting the computer, I cannot replicate the error. 
embarrased about this

**UPDATE 2**

I think I know why. 
The error happens when you create a second jupyter notebook session (or for that matter a second ipython session on cli).

am posting a longer error string just in case it helps somebody else

```
 RuntimeError: Init operations did not make model ready.  Init op: init,   init fn: None, error: Variables not initialized: global_step, hiddenlayer_0/weights, hiddenlayer_0/bias, hiddenlayer_1/weights, hiddenlayer_1/bias, hiddenlayer_2/weights, hiddenlayer_2/bias, dnn_logit/bias, centered_bias_weight, centered_bias_weight/Adagrad, hiddenlayer_0/bias/Adagrad, hiddenlayer_1/weights/Adagrad, hiddenlayer_1/bias/Adagrad, hiddenlayer_2/bias/Adagrad, dnn_logit/weights/Adagrad, dnn_logit/bias/Adagrad, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step, global_step,
```

Comment: Your code looks ok except for the line `iris = datasets.load_iris()` that is `iris = learn.datasets.load_iris()`. Fixing this issue I can run without any problem your code on my machine (with tensorflow 0.9)

Comment: @nessuno. Thanks I cannot replicate the error indeed. it works now . Sorry for waisting your time

Comment: @nessuno. I could replicate the error message I get but think it is not critical . Thanks

Comment: I had a similar issue. See the following for the solution for my case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128292/restoring-a-tensorflow-model-for-finetuning-with-slim-learning-train/40142695#40142695

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you try to run 2 tensorflow apps at the same time.

The first application will take up all of the GPU's memory.