# Restoring a tensorflow model for finetuning, with "slim.learning.train"

Tags: tensorflow

In tensorflow, with slim.learning.train (TF 0.11), I would like to restore a model from a checkpoint and continue the training. The model had a successful training session, and I would like to fine tune it. However, when I do that, TF crash with an error 
`Init operations did not make model ready.`

I do the training with:

```
tf.contrib.slim.learning.train(
    train_op,
    train_dir,
    log_every_n_steps=FLAGS.log_every_n_steps,
    graph=g,
    global_step=model.global_step,
    number_of_steps=FLAGS.number_of_steps,
    init_fn=model.init_fn,
    saver=model.saver,
    session_config=session_config)
```

I tried 3 alternatives:

#### #1

Following [this doc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/session_manager.py#L183)

```
model.init_fn = None
```

#### #2

```
with g.as_default():
    model_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(train_dir)
    if model_path:
        def restore_fn(sess):
            tf.logging.info(
                "Restoring SA&T variables from checkpoint file %s",
                restore_fn.model_path)
            model.saver.restore(sess, restore_fn.model_path)
        restore_fn.model_path = model_path
        model.init_fn = restore_fn
    else:
        model.init_fn = None
```

#### #3

```
with g.as_default():
    model_path = tf.train.latest_checkpoint(train_dir)
    if model_path:
        variables_to_restore = tf.contrib.slim.get_variables_to_restore()
        model.init_fn = tensorflow.contrib.framework.assign_from_checkpoint_fn(
            model_path, variables_to_restore)
    else:
        model.init_fn = None
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was solved. It happened because the saver (tf.train.Saver) was defined directly after the model build.

Instead, defining it following the train op definition, solved the issue.

Comment: Could you please share your code? I'm still having trouble with this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I define saver before the train op, and it works. Do you have some evidence about that claim ?